# animating a css reflection

Tags: css, webkit

I draw an icon and have a hover state in the css that plays a webkit animation to make the icon bounce. I want the reflection to bounce inversely, so that it stays put on the ground rather than following the icon, however the reflection property wont animate. Is something wrong or is there an alternative? I would like to avoid if possible adding elements to achieve this.

Please see this jsfiddle for my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2rmmU/

FYI this uses a webkit reflection therefore you'll need a webkit browser to see it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be `-webkit-box-reflect` isn't very robust and can't be animated.

However, you can achieve the effect you are looking for using pseudo elements.

```
#twitter_logo:after{
    content:'';
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:54px;
    left:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kmr8d/1/)

Now, display the svg again, [flip it](http://www.webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/), and apply a [gradient mask](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this something HTML5 Canvas is better suited for? That would be my suggestion for an alternative.

Comment: I'd say that it's a good alternative, but not a solution for the problem stated.